# lower-cased reserved keyword throws an error. Why?

Tags: php, parse-error

I've got this function

```
//admin
$router->route['/admin']->route['default'] = function() { //line 51
    if (isLoggedIn())                                     //line 52
        goTo('CMS');                                      //line 53 <---
    else                                                  //and so on
        goTo('login');  
};
```

but I've a Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting T_STRING in /path/index.php on line 53 
 What is the error?

Comment: because `goto` is a PHP language construct, not a function: http://php.net/goto. you can't replace/override language constructs with your own versions, e.g. `function echo($x) { print($x); } echo('hi mom')` would produce the exact same error you have.

Comment: but I've camel-cased it. The error is different too, so (in my humble opinion) this is not the problem

Comment: so? only php variable names are case sensitive. most everything else isn't.

Comment: This is actually very funny because the case doesn't match

Comment: I didn't know it. Thanks. Could you post an answer? I'll accept it

Comment: From the docs: `Note: Function names are case-insensitive, though it is usually good form to call functions as they appear in their declaration.` - http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`goto` is a reserved word. You can **NOT** override it, no matter how much you fiddle with upper-/lower-case variations:

```
php > function goto() { echo 'foo'; }
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'goto' (T_GOTO), expecting '(' in php shell code on line 1
php > function goTo() { echo 'foo'; }
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'goTo' (T_GOTO), expecting '(' in php shell code on line 1
php > function GOTO() { echo 'foo'; }
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'GOTO' (T_GOTO), expecting '(' in php shell code on line 1
```

You should never have been able to define your `goTo` function in the first place.

Comment: So does this mean that the parser is case insensitive?

Comment: only for variables. `$foo` and `$FOO` are completely different things. `function foo()` and `function FOO()` are the same.

Comment: Oh, I see. Still seems weird to me.

Comment: welcome to PHP, where consistency is merely a pipe dream.

Comment: Tested it out in Java and I got the result I expected. I defined method `DO` , `dO` and `Do`, everything works fine even if `do` is a keyword. :D

Comment: doesn't mean much. php grew organically out of someone's personal pet project to build their website. java was designed from the ground up by a "professional".

Comment: Yeah. It's a hacker's language but still gets the job done. "PHP at the Core: A Hacker's Guide"

Answer (score 0):

You need to rename `goTo()`*, e.g. into `forwardTo()`, because `goto` is reserved by PHP: http://php.net/goto

Weird, that PHP isn't warning you about that.

Furthermore I recommend to follow the PSR coding standards:
http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/

*Good point from @peter-featherstone: function names are case-insensitive.

Hope it helps